# Turn on num lock at log-in screen

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, windows-registry, numlock

I'm trying to turn "num lock" on when windows starts up, at login time. (I have Windows 10).

I edited the registry at the following path:

```
HKEY_USERS\Default\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators
```

to

```
2147483650
```

and when I restart the computer, num lock is not on by default. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

I have a HP Compaq 6000 Pro microtower.

Comment: @DavidPostill That did not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you miss the answer that said "There is also a 'boot with numlock on' setting in most modern bioses."?

Comment: I just tried that. The bios menu is different in windows 10. I couldn't find one that let's you change the numlock setting.

Comment: What is the make and model of your PC? What is the manufacturer listed in the BIOS?

Comment: hp compaq 6000 pro microtower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm trying to turn "num lock" on when windows starts up

> HP Compaq 6000 Pro microtower

- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to access Setup.
- Goto "Advanced" > "Device Options".
- Enable "Num Lock".

  > [image]

---

#### Using Computer Setup (F10) Utilities Computer

> Setup can be accessed only by turning the computer on or restarting
>   the system.
>
> To access the Computer Setup Utilities menu, complete the following
>   steps:
>
> 1. Turn on or restart the computer.
> 2. As soon as the computer is turned on, press <kbd>F10</kbd> when the monitor light turns green to enter Computer Setup.
>
>    Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bypass the title screen, if necessary.
>
>    Note: If you do not press <kbd>F10</kbd>  at the appropriate time,
>      you must restart the computer and again press  <kbd>F10</kbd> when the
>      monitor light turns green to access the utility.
> 3. Select your language from the list and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. A choice of five headings appears in the Computer Setup Utilities menu: File, Storage, Security, Power, and Advanced.

Source [HP Compaq 6000 Pro All-in-One PC - Computer Setup (F10) Utility](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01870907)

Comment: Thanks! I was using f8 instead of f10, so nothing would come up. I thought it was because windows 10 changed things. But anyways thanks! It's working now!

Answer (score 3):

There are three *levels* for such settings in the registry and you need to set `InitialKeyboardIndicators` value to `2` under *all* next keys:

- settings in `HKEY_USERS\.Default` alias `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18` are used by programs and services that run as Local System (as `S-1-5-18` is the security identifier for the Local System account). Important for logon screen/dialog as `winlogon.exe` runs under `SYSTEM` account.
- settings in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` are valid for currently logged user.
- (facultative) settings in `HKEY_USERS\Default` are the basis for new user profiles (not loaded most of the time; the hive loadable manually from `C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT`).

For instance, next settings should work as expected:

```
==> reg  query "HKU\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard" /V InitialKeyboardIndicators

HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard
    InitialKeyboardIndicators    REG_SZ    2

==> reg  query "HKU\DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard" /V InitialKeyboardIndicators

HKEY_USERS\DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard
    InitialKeyboardIndicators    REG_SZ    2

==> reg  query "HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard" /V InitialKeyboardIndicators

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard
    InitialKeyboardIndicators    REG_SZ    2

==>
```

FYI, `2147483648` = `2^31` = hexadecimal `0x80000000` (it sets the highest weight bit on in 32-bit integer arithmetic) seems to be a default value since *Windows 2000* times, maybe erst. Some estimate that this value means *do not override current LOCK status*. However, I have experienced another behaviour and therefore keep switching to above settings.

See also [CEPtor's post on July 1, 2010 at answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/want-to-set-num-lock-to-be-on-and-active-at/7b48ae6f-fa9c-4bc2-8359-81e0c5e5d6a2):

> It is important to use the find function to locate ALL keyboard keys
>   for `InitialKeyboardIndicators` and set them to the same value
>   setting. The value options are as follows:
>
> - `0` - Turn all indicators Off (NumLock, CapsLock, ScrollLock)
> - `1` - Turn **CapsLock** On
> - `2` - Turn **NumLock** On
> - `3` - Turn CapsLock and NumLock On
> - `4` - Turn **ScrollLock** On
> - `5` - Turn CapsLock and ScrollLock On
> - `6` - Turn NumLock and ScrollLock On
> - `7` - Turn all indicators On (NumLock, CapsLock, ScrollLock)

Warning: change only *numeric* `InitialKeyboardIndicators` values; keep those under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` referring to something like `USR:Control Panel\Keyboard`

Comment: Thanks you Yosef! (And no, that wasn't a mistake!) It was easier to just do it with the bios.